# How to validate HTML/CSS running in localhost?

Tags: php, html, css, apache, localhost

I have some local web pages running dynamically in localhost that need to be validated, Doing cut n paste is an option but very tedious.

What are some alternative offline validation options for HTML/CSS pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Install unicorn locally.](http://code.w3.org/unicorn/wiki/Documentation/Install)

Answer (score 2):

Firefox's [Web Developer toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/) has a "Validate local" option.

Comment: Thanks pekka but i went with UNICORN ^ !

Answer (score 2):

Try out the [HTML Validator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/249/) extension for Firefox - works locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the local page using [curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) and then validate it using a local validator or post again using `curl` to the [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) or your online HTML validator of choice. Or you can write a simple web spider in some scripting language and crawl the local web, validating each page as crawled. Sample crawler class in Perl:

```
package Test::Crawler;

use Moose;
use WWW::Mechanize;

has client => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'WWW::Mechanize',
    default => sub { WWW::Mechanize->new },
);

has handler => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'CodeRef',
    default => sub {},
);

sub crawl
{
    my ($self, $url, $visited) = (@_, {});

    # Already seen that.
    return if $visited->{$url}++;

    # Not seen yet, get.
    $self->client->get($url);
    $self->handler->($url, $self->client);

    # Follow all links.
    my @uris = map { $_->URI } $self->client->links;
    for my $uri (@uris) {
        # Skip mailtos, ftp and such.
        next if $uri->scheme;
        # Skip external links.
        next if $uri->host;
        $self->crawl($uri->rel, $visited);
    }
}
```

And a sample sub to validate using [validator.nu](http://validator.nu/):

```
sub is_valid {
    my ($code, $page_url) = @_;
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    my $url = 'http://validator.nu/?out=gnu';
    my $response = $ua->post($url, Content_Type => 'text/html', Content => $code);
    return $response->as_string !~ /error/;
}
```

Comment: thanks zoul, but unicorn is easer isn't, but still you can do some more stuff with this, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this rather old question when looking for the same. Here is what worked for me:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" \
     --data-binary "$(curl http://localhost:8080/url/to/test)" \ 
     https://validator.w3.org/nu/?out=gnu
```

See [the docs](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Service%3A-Input%3A-POST-body).